# Display UIAlertView when user can navigate anywhere while asynchronous web request executes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app with a `UINavigationController` architecture that can get up to three levels deep in the navigation stack. At the deepest navigaiton level the user sometimes make an asynchronous web call.

**Is there an easy, fast, and robust way to display a UIAlertView to the user regardless of where the user has navigated by the time the web call has been completed?** Here's what occurred to me:

- A very clumsy way to do this would be setting up every view
  controller as an observer of the class managing the web call.
- A less clumsy way, would be to give the web-class a protocol
  implemented by every view controller in the application. The web class could then call the protocol on the `UINavigationController`'s `visibleViewController`.

Comment: You can post a notification (using NSNotificationCenter) from your completion handler, then listen for that notification at another place in your app. (For example, in your app delegate)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a better approach would be to have another object handle the async requests. To be more precise, an object that has a single instance (singleton), sounds perfect for the task.

This way you don't have to worry about the location of the user in the navigation stack - when the request is complete, your singleton can show the alert.

Comment: I am using a singleton class. I did say in my post that I was using a distinct class to manage the async request. I didn't want to mention singleton because that tends to get people debating singletons. But having a singleton doesn't solve the problem of how to send a UIAlertView to the user wherever s/he happens to be browsing. My understanding is that showing a UIAlert from an NSObject can be hit-or-miss, but perhaps I am wrong about that?

Comment: Showing a system alert-view is not a hit and miss, doesn't matter if you're showing it from a NSObject. Just make sure to show it on the main thread.